# Probability of score a point

Tags: probability, contest-math

> A and B can score a point with probability 1/3. The two events are independent. A and B play at the same time with one play per round (the result of A doesn't interfere with B). What is the probability that in the same round at least one score a point?

**I have tried two paths but they don't converge to the same results so I am confused**

- Which is the right path?
- Why the other path is wrong?

#1st path

\begin{align*}
P(S) = ProbabilityOfAScore = P(1 - P(NoScore)) = P(1 - (2/3)^2) = 5/9
\end{align*}

#2nd path 
We have four possible outcomes after the first round:

\begin{align*}
S = Score;
N = NoScore;\\
1. SS\\
2. SN\\
3. NS\\
4. NN
\end{align*}

Now I compute the probability of each one of them:
\begin{align*}
P(SS)=1/3*1/3=1/9\\
P(SN)=1/3*2/3=2/3\\
P(NS)=2/3*1/3=2/3\\
P(NN)=2/3*2/3=4/9
\end{align*}
Because I am interested on the fist 3 events:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\text{P(SS)+ P(SN) + P(NS)}}{\text{P(SS)+ P(SN) + P(NS) + P (NN)}} =  13/17
\end{align*}

Comment: $\frac13\times\frac23=\frac29$ (not $\frac23$).

Comment: Yes, I did the math wrong! Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both methods give the same result, you just missed that $\frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{3}=\frac{2}{9}$ in the second derivation.